# Cannot read property 'set' of undefined | JavaScript | Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently doing some command handling for my bot and I encountered this error I can't seem to understand why it happens

Here is the error:

```
(node:10136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
at Object.execute (D:\Chest\Projects\Discord\terminalv2\commands\music\execute.js:36:28)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

The line in question is 36 but it **is** defined. I don't know what to do.

And here is my code:

```
const external = require('./../../externalCommands');
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

module.exports = {
name: 'play',
aliases: ['p'],

async execute(message) {
    const args = message.content.split(" ");
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

    if (!voiceChannel) {
        return message.channel.send("You need to be in a voice channel to play music! *bap*");
    }

    if (!args[1]) {
        return message.channel.send("You need to specify a youtube link! *bap*");
    }

    const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
    const song = {
        title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
        url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
    };

    if (!external.serverQueue) {
        const queueContruct = {
            textChannel: message.channel,
            voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
            connection: null,
            songs: [],
            volume: 25,
            playing: true,
        };

        external.queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);
        queueContruct.songs.push(song);
        
        var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        queueContruct.connection = connection;
        external.play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
    } else {
        external.serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        return message.channel.send(`I added **${song.title}** to the queue UwU`);
    }
},
};
```

Comment: The error means that `external.queue` is `undefined`

Comment: I completely understand what it means I don't understand why it happens when it is defined.

Comment: How do you know that `external.queue` is defined at that point in the code?

Comment: have you tried logging `external.queue`?

Comment: I just did and yes it returns undefined. I took external from `const external = require('./../../externalCommands');` and queue from `const queue = new Map();
exports.queue = queue;` in my externalCommands module

Comment: I fixed it just by bypassing the import and initializing it directly in the file.